Does blocking a number from a phone app blocks even SMS messages?
If I block a number from the first paragraph of this help, will SMS messages from the same number be blocked?

It depends on the apps.
Number blocking is usually implemented on the app level, and thus it only affects that specific app.
This also means that even numbers blocked on a phone app are not guaranteed to be blocked in other phone apps (if the user has multiple phone apps installed).
However, some apps may share the blocked numbers between apps like Google Phone (call) and Google Messages (SMS), or block both on multipurpose apps like Truecaller (call and SMS).

I haven't tested yet if the default phone app and default messaging app are not Google's, whether the SMS will still be blocked or not.
